# jQuery addClass and removeClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

currently working on a simple script that displays a nightime background if it's a certain time in the day and a daytime image if it's a different time of day. I am using jQuery to achieve this by adding a class if one is true, and adding a class if the other is true. Issue is... the code simply won't function properly. Curious about any possible solutions... thanks!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20) {
    $("document.body").addClass("day");
    $("document.body").removeClass("night");
  } else {
    $("document.body").addClass("night");
    $("document.body").removeClass("day");
  }
});
```

```css
.night {
  background-image: url('images/night.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="app-wrapper">
    <p id="date"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i dont see element with class body

Comment: Have you tried changing `$("document.body")` to `$("body")`?

Comment: `document.body` is not a valid selector I imagine.

Comment: It is `$(document.body)` or `$("body")` but not `$("document.body")`

Comment: @A.Wolff i think you mean `$(document .body) or $(document) or $("body")` i little typo :)

Comment: @guradio No i mean the `body` element: `$(document.body)` which is the same as `$('body')` selector, just a little faster i presume

Comment: Why the downvote... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:-

```
$("document.body").addClass("day");
$("document.body").removeClass("night");
```

to:-

```
$("body").addClass("day").removeClass("night");
```

(same for second-one too)

***Working demo example:-***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
  if (7 <= currentTime && currentTime < 20) {
    $("body").addClass("day").removeClass("night");
  } else {
    $("body").addClass("night").removeClass("day");
  }
});
```

```css
.night {
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.day {
  background-color: grey;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>APP</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-
hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="app-wrapper">

  <p id="date"></p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It isn't working... I quite literally copied and pasted the code and nothing.

Comment: @M97 Could it be because of cache issue?

Comment: @M97  yes i agreed with A. Wolff. clear your cache(browser) and check once

Comment: WOW. IT WAS A CACHE ISSUE. FML. Nonetheless, thank you guys so much for your help!

Comment: @M97  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `$("document.body")` with `$("body")`

Comment: this assuming that the OP refers to `<body>` what if not? this should be clarified first